# How to check to if something is in an array and only output if there is

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm workking on a shortcode for wordpress and did a loop and stored a few variables in an array some of my posts won't have anything in the array and i'm getting an error for the ones that do.

My two arrays are

```
$class_cards[]=array('card_count'=>$card_count,'has_term'=>$has_term,'card_img_class'=>$card_img_class,'card'=>$card,'card_title'=>$card_title,'card_mana'=>$card_mana,'card_slug'=>$card_slug);

$neutral_cards[]=array('card_count'=>$card_count,'has_term'=>$has_term,'card_img_class'=>$card_img_class,'card'=>$card,'card_title'=>$card_title,'card_mana'=>$card_mana,'card_slug'=>$card_slug);
```

I then output them with the code below, the issue I'm having is with most posts we have values stored in both arrays and output them and everything works great, but if we have values stored in just the $class_cards array and nothing in the neutral cards array I get the error

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/hsp/public_html/wp-content/themes/hsp/content/deck-info.php on line 264

The output looks like this, so what I'm asking is how can I check to make sure there is something in those arrays to fix this error

```
    // Output Class Cards
$output .= '<div class="class-cards">';
$output .= 'Class Cards ('. $total_class_cards .')';
$output .= '<span class="sc-deck-mana-cost"><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/icons/dust.png" />'.$crafting_cost.'</span>';
$i=0;
while($i<=20)
{
    foreach($class_cards as $row=>$value)
    {
        if($value['card_mana']==$i)
        {

            $output .= '
                <div class="card">
                    '. $value['card_count'] .' 
                    <div class="card-overlay"></div>
                    <div '. $value['card_img_class'] .' ><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/cards/'. $value['card'] .'.png"></div>
                    <div class="decklist-tooltip"><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/cards/'. $value['card'] .'.png"></div>
                    <span class="card-title">'. $value['card_title'] .'</span>
                    <span class="mana-icon"><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/icons/mana.png" /></span>
                    <span class="mana-cost">'. $value['card_mana'] .' </span>
                    <a class="dl-card-link" href="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/cards/'. $value['card'] .'/"></a>
                </div>
            ';

        }
    }
    ++$i;
}
$output .= '</div>'; // Close Div class-cards


// Output Neutral Cards
$output .= '<div class="neutral-cards">';

$i=0;
while($i<=20)
{
    foreach($neutral_cards as $row1=>$value1)
    {
        if($value1['card_mana']==$i)
        {

            $output .= '
                <div class="card">
                    '. $value1['card_count'] .' 
                    <div class="card-overlay"></div>
                    <div '. $value1['card_img_class'] .' ><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/cards/'. $value1['card'] .'.png"></div>
                    <div class="decklist-tooltip"><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/cards/'. $value1['card'] .'.png"></div>
                    <span class="card-title">'. $value1['card_title'] .'</span>
                    <span class="mana-icon"><img src="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/img/icons/mana.png" /></span>
                    <span class="mana-cost">'. $value1['card_mana'] .' </span>
                    <a class="dl-card-link" href="http://hearthstoneplayers.com/cards/'. $value1['card'] .'/"></a>
                </div>
            ';

        }
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: I can't see `$neutral_cards` in your code. Please post line 264 of `/home/hsp/public_html/wp-content/themes/hsp/content/deck-info.php`

Comment: Try to `print_r($class_cards );` before `foreach($class_cards as $row=>$value)`  if it is the line 264. `$class_cards` definitely empty or not set at all.

Answer (score 2):

Check this one

```
$Array = array_filter($yourArray );
if (!empty($Array)) {
echo "array not empty";
}else{
echo "array is empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function to do that

```
    if(count($class_cards) && count($neutral_cards)){
//foreach loop....
}
```

Comment: I think `!empty` is better.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
if (!empty($class_cards))
{
    foreach($class_cards as $row=>$value)
    { 
        ....
    }
}

....

if (!empty($neutral_cards))
{
    foreach($neutral_cards as $row=>$value)
    { 
        ....
    }
}
```

This will verify the array exists and that it isn't empty before trying to loop through it.

Comment: I thought `empty` checked if it existed, no?

Comment: It checks if it exists, but doesn't care if it's an array or not. But, I can see in the question that the OP is declaring the array outright so looks like `is_array` is redundant.